# Filtrar dois valores em uma variável do tipo texto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu quero pegar esses dois valores que se encontram na seguinte variavel:

```
let url = "https://localhost:44380/Manga/MangaPaginas/?idManga=1&idCapitulo=2";
```

o que eu quero são o idManga e o idCapitulo;

Eu estou usando javascript e quero gerar duas variáveis com os mesmos nomes.

Comment: Você quer pegar aonde? No backend? No frontend? Como estão vindo esses valores?

Comment: eu já estou pegando esse valor, eu quero filtrar por javascript.

Comment: este odigo está executando na pagina html

Comment: essa string é fixa, eu só preciso extrair os dois numeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entrada for uma url e o objetivo for ler os parâmetros de consulta use a interface [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) para a analise.

A propriedade [SearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) acessa individualmente os parâmetros de consulta.

```js
var url = new URL("https://localhost:44380/Manga/MangaPaginas/?idManga=1&idCapitulo=2");

console.log("idManga = " + url.searchParams.get("idManga"));
console.log("idCapitulo = " + url.searchParams.get("idCapitulo"));
```

Se o objetivo for listar os parâmetros de consulta e valores de uma url. Itere com `for of` sobre `SearchParams`.

```js
var url = new URL("https://localhost:44380/Manga/MangaPaginas/?idManga=1&idCapitulo=2");

for (const [key, value] of url.searchParams) {
  console.log(key + " = " + value);
}
```

Comment: vlw man, era isso mesmo que eu queria

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer isso de uma forma bem simples, usando uma expressão regular para pegar os dois números à partir da última barra `/`, sendo que o primeiro número é o valor de "idManga" e o segundo o valor de "idCapitulo".

Usando `url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/"))` irá retornar tudo que tiver da última barra pra frente, ou seja:

```
/?idManga=1&idCapitulo=2
```

Aí basta usar um `.match()` com a expressão regular `/\d+/g` que irá retornar uma array com os dois valores:

```
["1", "2"]
```

A expressão `/\d+/g` pega tudo que for número na string, criando a array separando os valores em cada índice, onde o índice `[0]` é o valor de "idManga" e o índice `[1]` o valor de "idCapitulo".

Veja como fica:

```js
let url = "https://localhost:44380/Manga/MangaPaginas/?idManga=10&idCapitulo=21";
const valores = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/")).match(/\d+/g);
console.log("idManga = ", valores[0]);
console.log("idCapitulo = ", valores[1]);
```